# 【Eureka&springCloud】java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: java, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I registered two services under Eureka. Resttemplate calls the interface of another service through the service name of one service. The following error occurred. If I call directly through IP, there will be no error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pz9hT.png)

I have annotated @ loadlanced under resttemplate to confirm that there is no error in the service name. Please ask us how to solve this bug

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Instead [edit] your question to include all relevant code & error messages as text.

Comment: Please provide code snippets that include the client and server application properties as well as the config for the load-balanced RestTemplate and the snippet with the call being made.

Answer (score 1):

In configuration, set

```
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
```